# Dynamic Linking of OpenSSL with python build

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, build, openssl, linker

I want to build python using ./config and make such that it picks up libssl.so and libcrypto.so during runtime. How to configure python for this? Also when I build new OpenSSL I just want to place libssl.so and libcrypto.so in place of old one’s and my python build should pick it up. How to do this?